# Solve $(x+1)^n=(x-1)^n$, assuming $x$ is a complex number and $n>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve $(x+1)^n=(x-1)^n$?
I assumed $x=a+bi$, getting the equation $((a+1)+bi)^n=((a-1)+bi)^n$.
How do I solve it using Moivre's n-th root theorem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$ \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^n = 1 \tag{1}$$
and since the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ is given by $\frac{y-1}{y+1}$, we have:
$$ x = \frac{\exp\frac{2\pi k i}{n}+1}{\exp\frac{2\pi k i}{n}-1}=-i\cot\frac{\pi k}{n},\qquad k\in\left[1,\ldots,n-1\right].\tag{2}$$

Comment: There seems to be a sign error for odd $n$.  For example, for $n=3$, one root given by $(2)$ is $x=i\tan(\pi/3)$.  Then, $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\frac{i\tan(\pi/3)+1}{i\tan(\pi/3)-1}=\frac{\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)}{-\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)}=-e^{2\pi/3}$ and $\left(-e^{2\pi/3}\right)^3=-1\ne 1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: you are right, now fixed, thanks.

Comment: Glad the comment was useful! It is interesting that there were 4 up votes before the edit.  ;-))

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé: so you have to solve $y^n=1$, then $\frac{z+1}{z-1}=y$, that is exactly what I did.

Comment: Is there any simples way to solve it?
I need to use basic concepts of complex numbers.
I wrote:
$(z+1)^n=(z-1)^n \leftrightarrow \frac{(z+1)^n}{(z-1)^n}=\frac{(z-1)^n}{(z-1)^n}=1 \leftrightarrow \left (\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n=1 \leftrightarrow \sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n}=\sqrt[n]{1}$
What do I do from there?
I thought I'd write $\frac{z+1}{z-1}=x$ and then solve $x^n=1=(\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi))$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé: by De Moivre's formula, the roots of $z^n-1$ (i.e. the $n$-th roots of unity) are given by $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k}{n}\right)=\cos\frac{2\pi i k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi i k}{n}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Tḧe only way to denote the n-th roots of unity is using the exponential?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: $x = 1$ is not a solution, so we might assume $x \neq 1$ and re-write this as:

$$\left(\frac{x + 1}{x - 1} \right)^n = 1$$

It boils down to just listing the $n$th roots of $1$ and computing $x$.

Comment: Why can I equal this equation to 1?

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé: by diving both sides of the initial equation by $(x -1)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

For $z^n=w$, one can write $w=we^{i2 \pi \ell}$ for integer $\ell$.  Then, solving for $z$ reveals that

$$z=w^{1/n}e^{i2 \pi \ell/n}$$

for $\ell =0,  1,  2,\cdots  n-1.$

---

Now for $z=x+1$ and $w=(x-1)^n$ we have that

$$x+1=(x-1)e^{i2 \pi \ell/n} \implies x = \frac{e^{i2 \pi \ell/n}+1}{e^{i2 \pi \ell/n}-1}=-i\cot{\pi\ell/n}\,\,\text{for}\,\,\ell =1,2,\cdots n-1$$